# How to get the Value Returned From Knex (Object in an Array thats in an Array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object, knex.js

I'm using a knex.raw query that ends with `.then(aTotal)` to get a count of a particular field matching the query.

```
knex.raw('This is my query').then((aTotal) => {
   console.log(aTotal) })
```

The console output shows this:

```
[ [ RowDataPacket { aTeamCount: 4 } ],
  [ FieldPacket {
    catalog: 'def',
    db: '',
    table: '',
    orgTable: '',
    name: 'aTeamCount',
    orgName: '',
    .
    .
    .a few more items } ] ]
```

I'm trying to 'extract' the value of `4` from `aTeamCount`.  It appears to me that there is an array of an array of 2 objects.  I'm not sure how drill into this arrangement so that it will `resolve(4)`.

Comment: Did you try `aTotal.toJSON()` ?

Comment: You should avoid making completely `raw` queries to be able to get less verbose response from server. If you add your query here some one may help to figure out better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose sometimes just writing out a question in detail can lead to better clarity.

Answer:

```
console.log(aTotal[0][0].aTeamCount)
```

Returned the value I was seeking (4)